# Consume Wcf Rest Service Issue

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0, rest

I have created a Rest WCF Service.

Service Contract

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IPracticeService
{
    [OperationContract]
    int AddInt(int value1, int value2);

    [OperationContract]
    double AddDouble(double value1, double value2);

    [OperationContract]
    string Hello();

    [OperationContract]
    Person GetPerson();
}
```

Class

```
public class PracticeService : IPracticeService
{
    public int AddInt(int value1, int value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

    [OperationBehavior]
    public double AddDouble(double value1, double value2)
    {
        return value1 + value2;
    }

    public string Hello()
    { 
        return "hello";
    }

    [WebInvoke(Method="GET",ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Name = "Abc";
        p.Age = 5;
        return p;
    }

Web Config 

<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="*" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="RestService.IRestServiceImpl" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web"></behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

So When I want Add ServiceRefrence This In the client It is giving me error.

```
The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
```

Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: '`http://mydomain:1121/Rest/RestServiceImpl.svc`'.
Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service `http://mydomain:1121/Rest/RestServiceImpl.svc`. The client and service bindings may be mismatched.
The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..
If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

So How can it will be resolved.

Comment: Did you rename your service and interface file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your config like this ,

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="PracticeService.IPracticeService" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
    <endpoint address="*" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="PracticeService.IPracticeService" behaviorConfiguration="web"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web"></behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```